# How to check system.collections.generic.dictionary ContainsValue for object value?

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to use the Dictionary method ContainsValue where Value is an object. I am using 
 dot Net Fiddler. https://dotnetfiddle.net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<int, Info> _dic = new Dictionary<int, Info>();
        _dic.Add(1, new Info()
        {Id = 1, Name = "Pawan"});
        _dic.Add(2, new Info()
        {Id = 2, Name = "Raj"});
        _dic.Add(3, new Info()
        {Id = 3, Name = "Shakya"});
        Console.WriteLine(_dic[1].Name);
        Console.WriteLine(_dic.ContainsKey(1));
        Console.WriteLine(_dic.ContainsValue({Id = 3, Name = "Shakya"})); //Error
    }

    public class Info
    {
        public int Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You did not override Gethashcode and Equals for Info. Also if you find your self using ContainsValue on a dictionary in your code you likely are using the wrong datastructure

Comment: you have to put `new Info(){Id = 3, Name = "Shakya"}`

Comment: It will return false. How do I get true value?

Comment: Can you please clarify what part of [ContainsValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a63811ah(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation is not clear?  To me it clearly states how it compares objects with default comparer and refers to following "... it returns an `EqualityComparer<T>` that uses the overrides of Object.Equals and Object.GetHashCode provided by T"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override the `GetHashCode` and `Equals`, also, you're missing the `new Info()`

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<int, Info> _dic = new Dictionary<int, Info>();
        _dic.Add(1, new Info()
        {Id = 1, Name = "Pawan"});
        _dic.Add(2, new Info()
        {Id = 2, Name = "Raj"});
        _dic.Add(3, new Info()
        {Id = 3, Name = "Shakya"});
        Console.WriteLine(_dic[1].Name);
        Console.WriteLine(_dic.ContainsKey(1));
        Console.WriteLine(_dic.ContainsValue(new Info(){Id = 3, Name = "Shakya"})); 
    }

    public class Info
    {
        public int Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode(){
            return Id;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if(obj.GetType()==typeof(Info))
            {
                Info i = obj as Info;
                return i != null && i.Id == Id && i.Name == Name;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to use `as` in `Equals`. `Info i = obj as Info` and check that the result there is not null.

Comment: @EvanFrisch just changed, thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you are adding objects to your dictionary you are adding objects of type `Info`. When you are running `ContainsValue` you are trying to pass in an anonymous type, you need to pass in an `Info` object just like when you add them to the dictionary.

```
Console.WriteLine(_dic.ContainsValue(new Info() {Id = 3, Name = "Shakya"}));
```

Also as Scott Chamberlain stated in the comments, you should overwrite `GetHashCode` and `Equals` for the info class to ensure that it does not try to compare the references and actually uses the contents of the `Info` class to determine if they are equal.

Comment: Your code returns false. How do get a true return?

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
Console.WriteLine(_dic.ContainsValue({Id = 3, Name = "Shakya"}));
```

to

```
Console.WriteLine(_dic.ContainsValue(new Info(){Id = 3, Name = "Shakya"}));
```

You can also try this.

```
var value = _dic.Where(x => x.Value.Id.Equals(3) && x.Value.Name.Equals("Shakya"));
if (!value.Equals(new KeyValuePair<int,string>()))
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Comment: Your code returns false

Comment: @PAWANRAJShakya updated the solution.